# Is it a bad practice to use @property as db.cursor?

Tags: python, sqlite, oop

The main question is it ok that I don't commit any executions and don't close db at all?

```
    @property
    def cursor(self):
        return sqlite3.connect('info.db').cursor()

    @property
    def weapon(self):
        weapon = self.cursor.execute(f'SELECT weapon FROM {self.name};').fetchone()[0]
        if weapon is not None:
            return Item.from_id(weapon) # ignore this function
    @weapon.setter
    def weapon(self, value):
        if self.weapon is not None:
            self.cursor.execute(f'INSERT INTO {self.name} (inventory) VALUES (?);',
                                (self.weapon.id,)) # ignore this attribute
        self.cursor.execute(f'UPDATE {self.name} SET weapon = (?) WHERE rowid = 1;', (value,))
```

Comment: This won't work when you need to reuse the same cursor, like when you loop over the results with `cursor.fetch()`

Comment: I know it, is it the only problem?

Comment: Making a new connection to the DB for every query also seems excessive. I suggest opening the connection once in the `__init__()` method, or maybe make a `conn` property that opens the connection the first time it's used and caches it.